# gprs issue on ppp connection LCP TermReq id=0x3

Tags: linux, gprs, pppd

following setup:

A remote linux PC with a wavecom gprs modem tries to connect to the orange romania gprs network via pppd and chat

We use this setup with different providers for a few hundred devices and had never issues in needing to reconfigure pppd options to be able to connect to the GPRS Provider.

I have access to that device via VPN so i can change config options on the fly (at least for now)

The chatscript itselfs seems to connect correctly .

Here the cutted logs:

```
AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0,0,"orange"

OK
AT+CGREG=1
OK

+CGREG: 0
AT+CGATT=1
OK

+CGREG: 2

+CGREG: 1
AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 24,0

OK
AT+CGAUTO=1
OK
at+cgdcont=1,"IP","internet"
OK
AT+CGACT=1,1
OK
AT+CGDATA=1
CONNECT
Serial connection established.
using channel 11
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/gsmmodem
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mru 1500> <asyncmap 0x0> <pcomp> <accomp> <auth pap>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x7e7f80ba> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap>]
rcvd [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <magic 0x7e7f80ba>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <mru 1500> <asyncmap 0x0> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <mru 1500> <asyncmap 0x0> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 192.168.10.1> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15> <bsd v1 15>]
rcvd [LCP TermReq id=0x3]
LCP terminated by peer
sent [LCP TermAck id=0x3]
Connection terminated.
```

here are the config options we currently use:

```
defaultroute
noipdefault
modem
/dev/gsmmodem
115200  
crtscts
persist
maxfail 1
debug
nodetach
novj
asyncmap 0
name " "
 usepeerdns
```

passive

http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml#debug
and
http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO/options.html
for some examples i did find on the subject and what i tried to change.

changing or removing the command line options MRU/MTU did not solve the issue, but only changed the response i got for the LCP ConfReq

/usr/sbin/pppd dump mru 1500 logfd 2 nodetach ipcp-accept-local ipcp-accept-remote connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/ppp/pppscript"

what i do find strange is the "conf_rej" auth pap part. 
if someone could point me to a direction where to look or what option i did need to fix i would be thankfully.

EDIT:
In response to  Michael Hampton comment i let the details of the sim contract be checked by my client:

It is a Prepaid card, but there is still enough Cash loaded on it , the contract has an unlimited GPRS traffic enabled, the simcard is activated (i just verified this with the client). The SimCard is working on an USB-UMTS Modem sticked to a laptop so in my opinion this rules out any issue with the Simcard and/or the provider connection itself.

Regards

Comment: The other end tore down the connection. Did someone forget to pay the bill?

Comment: this card is only 2-3 days old for all i know, i will check with my client about this (usually for an installation like this our client will just buy a new one)
but as this is a temporary installation this might actually be a prepaid card running out of cash.
will report the info later.

Comment: it is a prepaid card, but there is still enough Cash loaded on it , the contract has an unlimited GPRS traffic enabled, the simcard is activated (i just verified this with the client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason for this issue: my pap-secret file was somehow not loaded.
i was not able to fix the reading of the pap-secret, but adding the options user=xxx and pass=xxx to the file options did solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which was due to ofono , in ofonod roaming is disabled by default, 
I stopped ofono service then everything works fine.

https://github.com/intgr/ofono/blob/master/test/set-roaming-allowed

Comment: Consider being a little more specific with your detail and adding some reference and proof supporting what you state

Comment: additionally it would be nice to have not a python script depending on dbus for changing the roaming setting but instead giving the AT command to switch this.